# When it comes to middleware, what's the difference between config.ru and application.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack, middleware

Am I correct in understanding that `application.rb` runs middleware within the whole Rails stack, while putting something in `config.ru` pre-empts the Rails stack?

This means that if I say for example wanted access to the same session and other functionality as my Rails app, I should be putting my middleware in `application.rb`?  However if what I'm doing doesn't necessarily depend on Rails, it could go into `config.ru`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Rails/Rack expert but I have written a few rack apps and middleware. So I'll try my best stab at this.

There are two separate process in play here, initialization and runtime execution. During the initialization, any Rack compatible server is going to start with your `config.ru` file by default. In that case, anything coming before the `run YourApp::Application` line isn't going to have access to anything not explicitly included in the `config.ru` file. So `use MyMiddleware something: MyRailsModel.first` isn't going to work. If you were to do the same thing in `application.rb` or `environment.rb` or `config/initializers/*.rb` you'd be somewhere in the middle of the Rails initialization process and would have access to anything that had already been initialized, which is probably anything in Rails core that you would need.

But that is all just initialization, so it pretty much just applies to any config arguments you'd be sending to the middleware. During runtime, Rails has already been fully initialized and you should have access to any Rails classes, modules, etc. But you should definitely run `rake middleware` and take a look at the stack and see where your own middleware falls in relationship to the other middleware and the app itself. Rails isn't just the actual app, it also injects a lot of middleware into the stack. And depending on where your middleware falls in relation to other middleware in the stack will affect the state of the request.

As to sessions specifically, recent Rails versions use Rack sessions, so you shouldn't have any trouble accessing the session from Rack.

I know that's probably not as simple or definitive an answer as you'd like, but hopefully it helps. Rack and middleware seem complicated at first, but when you finally put the pieces together of how it all works, and see that there's not much magic going on behind the scenes and it's biggest strength really is its simplicity, it becomes a lot easier to understand.